# Creating login page for web application using oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I am trying to implement the login page of a web application using oracle ADF.The login username and password will be retrieved from a custom database table.As I am new in development using ADF really need some guidance on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to ADF you should not start with security. Anyways you can have a look at this article: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jan/o12adf-1364748.html

Comment: Thank You for your help.I went through this post but I don't think this is resolving my issue.I want to create a login screen for our web application.The login Username and password for that application are stored in a database table.Once logged in successfully the application will redirect a user to his homepage.I want to create this login page and impelement the logic using adf and really need some guidance as I am new in adf and Java.